# GraphQL optional Query Arguments

Tags: javascript, graphql

I know you can set arguments in a schema to default values but is it possible to make the argument `limit` argument completely optional in my GraphQL Schema?

Right now it seems like when I hit this without specifying a limit I think that's why I get `Int cannot represent non-integer value: undefined`

```
const schema = buildSchema(`
  companies(limit: Int): [Company]
...)
```

[image]

I want to be able to skip the limit so that it gets all companies.

In JS, I call it like this:

```
query: `query { 
          companies(limit: ${limit}) {
 ...
```

but sometimes I don't want to specify a limit.  So what is happening is the client is sending `crafters(limit: undefined)` and it's probably trying to convert that to Int.  I'm not sure how to not send `limit` in and how to make that entire param optional.

(I also read that from the **client** I should be instead specifying the arguments as **variables** like `query($limit: Int) {  companies(limit: $limit) {` I guess from my **client**, from **JS**?  If so how would I send in my limit **JS variable** into that?

Comment: specify a default value like so - https://graphql.org/learn/schema/#arguments

Comment: but if it's optional why do I want a default.  I just said I know you can set defaults, bht that I don't want to specify a default.  If there is no `limit` specified there's no default I want there.  This is for my DB query, if they don't specify a limit, then I don't want that limit in my DB query either.  So specifying an integer there is not what I want.  I'd have to specify like 0 if that's the case for limit and then check that at the DB JS code level that if it's 0 don't include limit which feels hacky compared to just checking if that limit is undefined lower down

Comment: I apologize, I simply spammed a link without deeply understanding your question. In my experience I've had too much data not to pass at least some sort of ceiling limit and have always to specify a default as a safety net. GL w/ your implementation

Answer (score 42, accepted):

Arguments in GraphQL are nullable (i.e. optional) by default. So if your type definition looks like this:

```
companies(limit: Int): [Company]
```

there is nothing else you need to do to make `limit` optional -- it already is. If you wanted to make `limit` required, you would make it non-nullable by appending a `!` to the type like this:

```
companies(limit: Int!): [Company]
```

The errors you are seeing are unrelated to the type of the `limit` argument. The issue is with the query that you're sending, which based on the error messages, looks something like this:

```
query ($limit: Int){
  companies (limit: undefined) {
    # ...
  }
}
```

There's two issues here: One, you are defining a variable ($limit) that you never actually use inside the query (as indicated by the second error). Two, you are setting the limit to `undefined`, which isn't a valid literal in GraphQL.

Instead of using string interpolation, you should use variables to pass any dynamic values to your query. For example:

```
query ($limit: Int){
  companies (limit: $limit) {
    # ...
  }
}
```

If the variable is nullable (notice we used `Int` instead of `Int!`), then it can be omitted from the request entirely, effectively making the value of the argument undefined server-side. It's unclear how you're sending your requests to the server, but assuming you're not using some client library, you can check the documentation [here](https://graphql.org/learn/serving-over-http/) for how to structure your request. Otherwise, check your library's documentation for how to correctly use variables with your query.

Answer (score 2):

Below is an example of how you could define a query on client and pass non-required argument. Not sure about your client-side config, but you may want to use a lib like graphql-tag to convert string to AST.

```
const GET_COMPANIES = gql`
  query Companies($limit: Int) {
    companies(limit: $limit) {
      ... // return fields
    }
  }
`;
```

Comment: I'm doing fine without a third party.  I prefer not to use Apollo and stuff like that. I just use JS constants and a query object with string inside. Example: ```const query = {
  query: `query { 
    companies(limit: ${companyLimit}) {
     ${fields}
    }
   }`,
 };``` But it's working without specifying variables so why is it necessary?  LOL I just broke stack comments

Comment: Not completely clear on how your client implementation is working, but based on what I see above, you're literally passing `undefined` with your use of the template literal. If you pass an argument, it needs to be of type Int by your schema def. With what I recommended, you can invoke the query with no variables and should work fine.

Comment: thanks, makes sense.  It was already optional then, I just needed to handle the client query better by taking the limit out.